# Changing Background of Edit Button - UITableView iOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have a UITableView which when edited looks as follows :

[image]

Is it possible to somehow change the background behind the delete symbol so that it is not white ?

Comment: have you tried cell.backgroundColor for this?

Comment: Change cell background color to clearColor

Comment: cell.backgroundColor produces no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this help you

```
UIView *cellBackView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
cellBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.cellBackgroundView = backView;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem ist that contentView gets shifted to the right when you are in editing mode, and because of this all its subviews will move to the right as well.
If your background is an imageView you should not add is as subview to `contentView`, set it as `backgroundView` of the cell instead.

Since you can't setup backgroundView from interface builder I would recommend to create a  custom subclass of your cell and put the background creation into `awakeFromNib`.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:...];
}
```